How can I make sure my arrays have been updated when looping through them?
I'm running two Axios GET requests. After the first GET finishes, I loop through the response to simplify each returned object so it only contains what I need (data[i] within the first loop, below). From there I run a second GET to retrieve child data from the individual objects that I can't access without another request, accessed by the "key" value (query2).
I then run a second loop to attach all the children objects retrieved from the second response and attach them iteratively to the parent object (data[i]).
The problem I'm having is that often (not always) the second loop throws a

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'episodes')
at newAdditionCheck (...bot\plexTV.js:89:26)
at runMicrotasks ()
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

error at the data[i].episodes.push(data2[j]) point. When I log the different objects within the loop they exist as they should, so my only guess is some of the loops are finishing before others, but any input or fixes would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
let baseURL1 = `http://${plexKeys.hostname}:${plexKeys.port}`;
let baseURL2 = `/?X-Plex-Token=${plexKeys.token}`;

const response = await axios({
  method: "GET",
  url: `${baseURL1}${query}${baseURL2}`,
});
let data = response.data.MediaContainer.Metadata;
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i] = {
    name: data[i].parentTitle,
    key: data[i].queryToken,
    episodes: [],
  };
  query2 = data[i].key;
  const response2 = await axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: `${baseURL1}${query2}${baseURL2}`,
  });
  let data2 = response2.data.MediaContainer.Metadata;
  for (let j in data2) {
    data2[j] = {
      series: data2[j].grandparentTitle,
      season: data2[j].parentTitle,
    };
    data[i].episodes.push(data2[j]);
  }
  continue;
}


There's no need for continue at the bottom. Loops automatically continue unless you break out.

Make sure you declare i with for (let i ...)

await axios(...) should ensure that the rest of the code doesn't run until the AJAX call completes. Everything in this loop should behave as if it's sequential.

When you log the objects, use console.log(JSON.stringify(object)). This will ensure that you get a snapshot of the object at that time, not a live object that can change if it's modified asynchronously.

Shouldn't there be a / at the end of baseURL1?

I don't see how you could get that error for data[i].episodes, but not for data[i].key a few lines earlier. Something must be changing i, probably because you didn't declare it to be local, and you're calling something else that you didn't show us.

You could also replace that entire loop with data[i].episodes = data2.map(({grandparentTitle, parentTitle}) => ({series: grandparentTitle, season: parentTitle}))
